# Why aren't my citations printing and my bibliography showing up?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, zotero

I've created a .bib file using Zotero and placed it in the same folder as the .tex file. This is the document code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\title{The Effects of Selective Logging on Gliding Vertebrates}
\maketitle

TEXT  


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{The Effects of Selective Logging on Gliding Vertebrates}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If that is the complete document you are missing a call to your bibliography handler (bibtex, natbib, biblatex) and a specification of your actual file. Something along the lines of \usepackage{biblatex} and \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`? Also, you shouldn't have  spaces in the name of your .bib file.

Comment: Does your real document contain any `\cite` instructions? (The sample document you posted above does not.)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included your `.bib` file so I will assume its contents is not the source of your problem.

Bernard correctly states that your `.bib` file should not contain spaces; this prevents BibTeX from compiling correctly. In the MWE below, I've renamed it.

The only other thing (from your MWE provided) that is preventing the citations to work properly is the lack of a `\cite{}` command - given your plain citation style, you won't need to include any other packages.

`document.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\title{The Effects of Selective Logging on Gliding Vertebrates}
\maketitle

Cite here \cite{TestCitation}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{effects-selective-logging-vertebrates}
\end{document}
```

`effects-selective-logging-vertebrates.bib`

```
@Inbook{TestCitation,
    author="Author, The",
    title="The Book Title",
    year="2021",
    publisher="Springer",
    address="Address",
    pages="1--14",
}
```

Output:
[image: citation-mwe]

Compile as per Bernard's comment.

Hope this helps!